# Read user input (which should be a linux command) and execute

Tags: linux, csh

I wish to write a simple csh script which loops through all computers in a network and executes a command that is input at the command line

`echo -n "Please enter command you would like executed on all computers > \n "
set command = "$<"`

say the user enters ls | grep something. How would I then execute this command in the following line? I tried
`$command` which works fine for input such as `echo "Hello World"`. I get the following error for ls | grep something

`ls: |: No such file or directory
ls: grep: No such file or directory
ls: something: No such file or directory`

Ideally, I would want to enter several commands at the command line before looping through each computer in the network (which I can already do) and execute. Eg say I wish to copy two different files

`sudo cp ./bin/elastix /usr/bin; sudo cp ./lib/transformix /usr/lib`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> loops through all computers in a network and executes a command that is input at the command line

You would be perhaps using ssh so you would do something like:

```
ssh $hostname "$command"
```

I'm not a csh user so I may have the syntax wrong. For current machine you may use the `eval` shell command that should interpret any command sequences, not only simple commands.

Comment: Thanks. The problem seemed to be executing the command on the current machine. I was already intending on using `ssh $hostname "$command"`